# WCF - need to start client host from server

Tags: wcf

in WCF discovery example, i have server and client host. I need to start client host from server. how to do that.

in server, i have a method in discovery contract.

```
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

in client host, i point to the discovery contract.

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:8000/discovery/scenarios/Myservice/",System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
Console.WriteLine(baseAddress);
using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFDiscoveryContract.Service1), baseAddress))
{
    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WCFDiscoveryContract.IService1), new WSHttpBinding(), string.Empty);
    serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    serviceHost.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Press to terminate service.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

in server i have another solution which searches for a discovery contract and calls the method GetData().

```
ServiceClient.ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceClient.ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
client.Endpoint.Address = serviceAddress;
string ss = client.GetData(1);
```

For calling GetData method, client host should be running. Is there any way to start the client host from the server.

Comment: Do you want to run Server and Client at the same time or you want to run client host from Server?

Comment: when i run the server, it should trigger the client host.

Comment: So, your client will be listening Server response? If it is so, then you can send responses from Server periodically and then client can do some task based on response receive.

Comment: Initially the client is not in running mode. i want to start the client from server.

Comment: How will you know that client is not in running state?

Comment: Discovery service should find that client host.
 DiscoveryClient discoveryClient =
                  new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
            var Services =
                 discoveryClient.Find(new FindCriteria(typeof(WCFDiscoveryContract.IService1)));
            discoveryClient.Close();

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/469549/WCF-4-0-Discovery is this you want?